# determine side of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to check if the div is on the left or the right side so that when the div is on the right side it changes the class. Is this possible with JS?

This is what I have right now:

[image]

And this is what I want as outcome:

[image]

So basically that it just flips everything around. This is my code:

```css
.box-area {
  background-color: #BA5e8e;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
body > div.area > div > div.area-blocks > div > div > div.col-xs-8 > div {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: roboto-thin;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
body > div.area > div > div.area-blocks > div > div > div.col-xs-8 {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
body > div.area > div > div.area-blocks > div > div > div.col-xs-4 > div > img {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
body > div.area > div > div.area-blocks > div > div > div.col-xs-4 > div {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
body > div.area > div > div.area-blocks > div > div > div.col-xs-4 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="area-blocks">
  <div class="box-area col-xs-6">
    <div class="area-box">
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="area-file-name">
          <span>
            Bike trips on lombok
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="area-file-type">
          <img src="includes/img/pdf.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-area col-xs-6">
    <div class="area-box">
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="area-file-name">
          <span>
            Bike trips on lombok
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="area-file-type">
          <img src="includes/img/pdf.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seemed to have missed off some of your CSS in the sample as it doesn't match your image. That said you don't need JS or jQuery to achieve this. In CSS use the `:nth-child(2n)` selector, instead of your class, to change every second instance of the required elements to align to the right

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I know but it will load in a lot of those by PHP and then I will not be able to select it right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean as you don't need to select anything. If you do this in CSS it's a few lines and you're done.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Wait I'll try your code first

Comment: I added an answer for you, hopefully it shows what I mean a little clearer.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try to boil down your example to a [minimal, complete, verifiable one](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - you have a lot going on here that isn't specifically relevant to your question. That makes it harder for the rest of us to understand, which might discourage some people from putting in the time to help. And, just as importantly, boiling it down to the essential problem is a really great learning tool to help you understand what's happening and what the solution might be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need JS or jQuery to achieve this. In CSS use the `:nth-child(2n)` selector, instead of your class, to change every second instance of the required elements to align to the right. Try this:

```css
.box-area {
  background-color: #BA5e8e;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

/* this is the boxes to align to the right */
.box-area:nth-child(2n) {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}

body > div.area > div > div.area-blocks > div > div > div.col-xs-8 > div {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: roboto-thin;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
body > div.area > div > div.area-blocks > div > div > div.col-xs-8 {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
body > div.area > div > div.area-blocks > div > div > div.col-xs-4 > div > img {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
body > div.area > div > div.area-blocks > div > div > div.col-xs-4 > div {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
body > div.area > div > div.area-blocks > div > div > div.col-xs-4 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
<div class="area-blocks">
  <div class="box-area col-xs-6">
    <div class="area-box">
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="area-file-name">
          <span>
            Bike trips on lombok
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="area-file-type">
          <img src="includes/img/pdf.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-area col-xs-6">
    <div class="area-box">
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="area-file-name">
          <span>
            Bike trips on lombok
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="area-file-type">
          <img src="includes/img/pdf.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also note that I added bootstrap to the example as I realised that was the styling your example was missing.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer to your question, but I thought it was a worthwhile tangent and it won't fit in a comment.

I recommend you read [MDN's Writing efficient CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS). It's from back when minimal CSS made a noticeable difference in rendering speed. As they mention, that isn't such a concern now, and some of their "never *ever* do this" should definitely be taken with a grain of salt… but it'll still help you write css (and html) that's easier to work with.

You might have other reasons to include those extra `<div>`s etc, but the code you gave us is equivalent to this:

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css';
.box-area {
  background-color: #BA5e8e;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: roboto-thin;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}

.area-file-name,
.area-file-type {
  padding: 0;
}

.area-file-name div {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 10px auto 0;
}

.area-file-type img {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 6px 5px 6px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="area-blocks">
  <div class="box-area col-xs-6">
    <div class="col-xs-8 area-file-name">
      <div>
        Bike trips on lombok
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 area-file-type">
      <img src="includes/img/pdf.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-area col-xs-6">
    <div class="col-xs-8 area-file-name">
      <div>
        Bike trips on lombok
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 area-file-type">
      <img src="includes/img/pdf.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13825496)

Comment: I'm glad you explained your vote to delete. Not sure what made you think it's a new question - as I wrote, this direct response is a long-form comment aimed at guiding the OP towards HTML and CSS best practices

Answer (score 0):

Create one JS Function  runs in document.Ready on your page. In your JS function verify the div position.

Comment: That's is not helpful at all

Answer (score 0):

I dont know my code helpful for you or not. I just create a css class "box-area-2" and replace with box-area on right side div. I also comment out where I have change's Total 5 changes in Html, and one class add in css. Here is also [live fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/m377dt6p/)

```css
    .box-area {
  background-color: #BA5e8e;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.box-area-2 { /* box-area-2 create for right side div */
  background-color: #BA5e8e;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
body > div.area > div > div.area-blocks > div > div > div.col-xs-8 > div {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: roboto-thin;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
body > div.area > div > div.area-blocks > div > div > div.col-xs-8 {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
body > div.area > div > div.area-blocks > div > div > div.col-xs-4 > div > img {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
body > div.area > div > div.area-blocks > div > div > div.col-xs-4 > div {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
body > div.area > div > div.area-blocks > div > div > div.col-xs-4 {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <div class="area-blocks">
  <div class="box-area col-xs-6">
    <div class="area-box">
      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <div class="area-file-name">
          <span>
            Bike trips on lombok
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div class="area-file-type" style="float:right;"><!-- add float right  -->
          <img src="includes/img/pdf.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-area-2 col-xs-6"> <!-- add box-area-2 class here -->
    <div class="area-box">
      <div class="col-xs-4"> <!-- change the postion of the column  -->
        <div class="area-file-type">
          <img src="includes/img/pdf.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-8"><!-- change the postion of the column  -->
        <div class="area-file-name">
          <span style="float:right;"><!-- add float right  -->
            Bike trips on lombok
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```